# Can't deploy iOS6 SDK build to iOS7

Tags: ios, xcode

I am having difficulty running an app built with iOS 6 SDK on an iPhone 4S with ios7.  Even a newly created app won't run. I am receiving an error "No provisioned iOS devices are available with a compatible iOS version". Shouldn't I be able to build and run an ios6 app on ios7?  I cannot update the Mac past Lion so an ios7 build and xcode5 are out of the picture.

Comment: Bad news is that as of today all Apps need to be build using Xcode 5 and iOS 7 SDK. I see you error before and the only way I've managed to fix it is by running using Xcode 5 and the iOS7 SDK to run the app.

Comment: You may be able to put Mountain Lion on a machine that isn't officially supported with the MLPostFactor package. Look at: http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1325709  I'm running 10.8.4 on a MacPro 1,1 and a MacBook Pro 2,1 using this and it has worked for Xcode 5 and iOS 7 without any problems.  Of course YMMV but you should at least know about your options.